# Ruby 3.2 - Keyword Arguments Issue with a single argument

Tags: ruby

Im looking through an old code base, and can see examples of method signatures with single keyword arguments.

Is this something you would typically do in Ruby? It seems a tad odd. I would expect to see this used where you can have one or more args.

I've noticed in a Ruby 3.2 upgrade, that this syntax falls over when running the test suite.

Is this something that is removed in Ruby 3.2, Ive looked at the docs but can't determine the issue.

```
def greet(name: "Guest")
  puts "Hello, #{name}!"
end

greet(name: "Alice")  # Output: Hello, Alice!
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> [...] method signatures with single keyword arguments.
>
> Is this something you would typically do in Ruby?

It depends on the use case. Even with a single argument, a keyword argument can help to communicate the argument's intent more explicitly, e.g. `obj.clone(freeze: false)` or `Time.now(in: '+0200')`.

Without a name, it  wouldn't be as clear what the argument does: `obj.clone(false)`

In your case, it could be a hint to pass a *name* instead of – for example – a rich user object or a greeting message. Or maybe the author just preferred the code to be more explicit.

---

> I've noticed in a Ruby 3.2 upgrade, that this syntax falls over when running the test suite.
>
> Is this something that is removed in Ruby 3.2

The example you've shown is perfectly valid in Ruby 3.2 and doesn't cause any errors. One major change in Ruby 3.x was the removal of implicit hash-to-keyword-argument conversion:

```
hash = { name: "Alice" }

greet(hash)
# Ruby 2.6: works
# Ruby 2.7: works but prints deprecation warning (when enabled)
# Ruby 3.x: raises ArgumentError
```

If you have something like the above in your old code base, you have to add `**` now to convert the hash to keyword arguments explicitly:

```
greet(**hash)
```

Answer (score 1):

Keyword arguments exist to eliminate so called [Connascence of Position](https://connascence.io/position.html#in-function-arguments), which means you need to remember the order of arguments. If you change the order, all calling locations must also be updated.

Whether Keyword Arguments are applicable or not is decided by the designer. I see nothing wrong with your example, but would probably stick to regular positioned arguments because there is only one argument and it is not particularly hard (at least to me) to guess what  you need to pass.

P.S. Keyword Arguments feature is not removed from Ruby and unlikely will ever be. Not sure what docs are you referring to.

Comment: kwargs are updated in ruby 3.2, ive made many changes to use double splats etc where they are passed, but in this one instance, where only onekwarg is required, im asking is it not pointless?